ollama and google colab locally is producting errors whilst pure python is not
I've installed and can run against ollama locally with llama3. However I cannot seem to get this working in a local google colab. The following python code runs just fine as a python.py. But when I run a local docker instance and connect my colab project to that local colab instance, I cannot get the code to run.
import ollama
MODEL = 'llama3'


def llm_response(content):
    response = ollama.chat(
    model=MODEL,
    messages=[
        {

            "role": "user",
            "content": content,
        },
        ],
    )
    txt = response["message"]["content"]
    return txt

In colab this returns:
ConnectError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py in map_httpcore_exceptions()
     68     try:
---> 69         yield
     70     except Exception as exc:

20 frames
ConnectError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

When just doing the following:
import ollama
ollama.chat(model=MODEL, messages=[{"role": "user", "content": "The cat sat on the mat"}])

The local colab is being created with:
sudo docker run -p 127.0.0.1:9000:8080 us-docker.pkg.dev/colab-images/public/runtime

I followed the following link for creating the local runtime.
https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html

Can you run a simple print("hello") from  your colab project connected to that local colab instance?

Are you running the following sudo docker run -p 127.0.0.1:9000:8080 us-docker.pkg.dev/colab-images/public/runtime from the colab notebook?

@ggordon No, I'm running this in local terminal and then connecting to the local instance in my browser.

@lmlima Yes, the local colab works just fine. Its just the connection issue. I'm sure this has to do with tunneling through on the right ports that are listened to by ollama.

Are you running the ollama server in another docker instance or in docker host machine? As it is a connection issue, can you describe better how did you setup everything?
